# Pointwise convergence by definition.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, definition

How can I prove that the sequence  $f_n$ = 
\begin{cases}
0  & \text{,if $\vert x \vert \gt \frac{1}{n}$ } \\
n(1 + nx), & \text{,if $ \frac{1}{n}\le x \le 0$ } \\
n(1-nx) &\text{if $ 0\le x \lt \frac{1}{n} $}
\end{cases}

converges pointwise ?

My attempt was using the archimedean property, i.e , for any $x$ I am able to find an $n^*$ such that $\vert x \vert \gt \frac{1}{n^*}$ and then we that $f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ pointwise. Is that correct ? How can I use the definition to write this in a better way? Thanks ! ;)

Comment: $\frac 1n \leq x \leq 0$ makes no sense when $n \geq 1$

Comment: @ThePortakal It makes perfect sense, it just doesn't happen "most of the time".

Comment: There seems to be a problem at $x=0$.

Comment: @GitGud you are right, thanks :)